# What is a simple way to find clusters for datapoints?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I know in unsupervised machine learning there are a number of ways to find clusters. However, I want a way that is simple to explain and is not unpredictable. Also I have very few data points.

Is there anyway to do  the clustering via the gradient or 2nd derivative? Thank you!

**Specifications of my data:**

1. number of data points = about 20 only
2. maximum number of cluster= 4
3. number of data points in a cluster can vary

**Updated**
My data points are only 1-d. The x-axis are strings like John, Dick, Harry.

```
|Name | Revenue1| 
|Peter| 0.5     | 
|Jane | 0.7     | 
|John | 1.4     | 
|Dick | 1.5     | 
|Harry | 1.45   |
```

On further thoughts, I would like to group based on similar values in Revenue1.

So

1. Grp 1: Peter, Jane
2. Grp 2 : John, Dick, Harry

So how can I do the grouping in Python? Thank you

Comment: can you explain further? by datapoints you mean spatial coordinates like (2,3), (5,1), etc..? How would you obtain the gradient from there?

Comment: @SandiaDeDia: Have updated my query. Thanks!

Comment: A really easy to understand method is to simply select those groups in which any member has at least one other member below a given distance. In one dimension this is very easy:
 1. Order the data (list) from low to max revenue
 2. loop through the data, if the distance between revenue[i] and revenue[i+1] is above maximum distance revenue[i+1] is not in the cluster of revenue[i]

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a simple working example where any member of a cluster has at least one other member below a given distance maxDis:

```
def cluster( values,  maxDis):      
    values.sort() 
    clusterId=[]
    count=0
    for kk in range(1,len(values)):
        if values[kk]-values[kk-1]>maxDis:
           count=count+1
        clusterId.append(count)
    return clusterId,values

a=[10,54,12,14,15,56,50,100,125]

clusterID,revenue = cluster(a,7)

#RESULT:
#revenue=[10, 12, 14, 15, 50, 54, 56, 100, 125]
#clusterID =[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```